# OpenGL ES 2.0: What's the correct way to dynamically set texture coordinates in a GLSL vertex shader?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, shader, textures

I'm trying to do the following in a vertex shader:

```
...
attribute vec2 tCoordIn;
uniform vec2 tCoordScale;
uniform vec2 tCoordOffset;
varying vec2 tCoordOut;

void main() {
    ...
    tCoordOut = (tCoordIn * tCoordScale) + tCoordOffset;
    ...
}
```

with no luck if I use sensible values for `tCoordScale` and `tCoordOffset`.

<strike>Will this work if I do nothing else wrong, or does it go against the GLSL specification?</strike>

It only works approximately when I use some very outlandish scale numbers, and add some unexpected number to both x and y offsets. Does the GPU ever pad out the texture image so that `0` and `1` no longer refer to the beginning and end of the image which you put in?

My texture "atlas" is 2048x2048 and the target is 75x75 pixels (it is for a quad) and is offset at (0.0, 0.75) on the texture (I've verified this on an output image).

Therefore I presumed that `tCoordScale` should be 75 / 2048 = (0.0366, 0.0366) approx. (given that my input texture coordinates are (0.0, 0.0) (1.0, 0.0) (0.0, 1.0) (1.0, 1.0) ) and that `tCoordOffset` should simply be (0.0, 0.75).

However it only appears approximately correct when `tCoordScale` is around (0.000045, 0.000045) (about 814 times smaller in each direction than what I would expect to need for a 75/2048 scaling) and when `tCoordOffset` is about (0.018, 0.768) (i.e. when I add about `0.018` to the value of both the `x` and `y` offset values).

I have verified this both by sending the values in as uniforms, and hard-coding the same values in the shader itself. (I'm sending the 2048x2048 image in via `GLUtils.texImage2D` on Android).

What is happening here? Why does it only accept these modified values? How do I ensure that I am always able to scale and translate the texture coordinates exactly correctly within my texture atlas, regardless of which device it's on?

Any insights would be appreciated, or any experiences from anyone who has got something like this working.

Comment: This should work perfectly fine, your error is elsewhere.

Comment: @Christian Rau, I literally can't find anything else wrong with my prog. I know it's using the right vertex shader as it reflects other changes I make to that shader. I know it's sending uniforms ok as it reflects changes I make to other uniforms, just not those I mentioned above, even though they're sent in exactly the same way (even other vec2s). My `tCoordScale` is e.g. 0.036, 0.036 and `tCoordOffset` is e.g. 0.0, 0.75, & the output is exactly like `tCoordOut = tCoordIn` no matter what those values are. Are you sure it is mandatorily supported in the GLSL version specified by OpenGL ES 2.0?

Comment: Well, you're putting in a normal `vec2` uniform, you're putting in a normal `vec2` attribute, you're putting out a normal `vec2` varying, you're doing standard vector arithmetic. I cannot imagine this to magically not work because of some weird reason (*"hey, he's computing a textrue coordinate from a uniform, that's not allowed!"*, huh?). All the features you're using are indeed *"mandatorily supported"* by OpenGL ES 2.0, it wouldn't be OpenGL ES 2.0 if they weren't.

Comment: @ChristianRau, thanks for your insights. It's the numbers I'm using. Something seems to appear approximately right when I use some very outlandish scale numbers, and add some unexpected number to both x and y offsets. Does the GPU ever pad out the texture image so that `0` and `1` no longer refer to the position on the image which you put in? I've updated the question asking for the correct way to dynamically set the texture coordinates.

Comment: Check if you are marking you vertex attribute in play to be normalized . Also try some easier number, like using the tile at offset 0 (0,0)

Comment: @TraxNet, if I'm already passing t coords in the range `0.0f` to `1.0f`, then I don't need any normalization, right? Maybe I'm passing v coords into my intended t coords array. At least that's what it seems like. There must be some mistake in the way I'm creating my vertex buffer object. My order is `glBindBuffer(vBufferId)` -> `glBufferData(vData)` -> `glBindBuffer(0)` -> `same for tCoords` -> then for each shader program I'm calling `for(){glBindBuffer(vBufferId); glEnableVertexAttribArray(vHandle); glVertexAttribPointer(vHandle etc.); -> same for tCoords;}`. This ordering must be wrong.

Comment: There is a flag when calling glVertexAttribPointer that tells the driver to normalize the buffer. That means if you pass an unsigned or signed byte, they get normalized to [0,1]. The order is correct, try outputing the texture coords as colors, that may help.